# yii2 render after post-request

Tags: javascript, post, view, yii2, render

I have a view with a gridview with checkboxcolumn and a google-map (2amigos). The user selects the machines to display in the map by selecting the corresponding items in the gridview. A html-button submitts the selected keys to the controller. Following the controler code (dataProvider gets updated by post-request):

```
//some code before render   
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider(['query'=>$query, 'pagination'=>false]);
return $this->render('locating', [
    'model' => $model,
    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

And this is the js-script for the html-button:

```
$('#showButton').click(function(){
    var keys = $('#w0').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
    $.post("http://localhost:8080/eddb1/frontend/web/index.php?r=tracking/locating",
    {'keylist': keys},
    function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

The problem is, that with the post request the result of php-render command gets writen as a html-string to the post-response but the view doesn't get re-rendered. If I do the same with an activeForm instead of a gridview (to select the machines) and a submit-button the page gets re-rendered as it should (but this way doesn't work for me because I need the gridview with filter and sorting). What can I do that the map (or the view) gets re-rendered with the post-request?

Comment: Please show the controller code...

Comment: Don't understand why...but I will post the whole controller-code

Comment: Any ideas for that problem?

Comment: if  I understand correctly  you're trying to use a gridview and an active form in the same view. What kind of class gridview you're using? the normal class of Yii2 gridview?

Comment: no, you understood it wrong: I need to use a gridview instead of a activeform...with activeform and multiselect-field everything is working fine but not if I'm using gridview with a normal parameter-post request as shown in the code above.

Comment: I'm using kartik-grid by the way...If you red my question the the parameters get postet correctly to the action. Also the new dataprovider gets calculated correctly (after post). The problem is the re-render of the map with the new dataprovider-data.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [*renderAjax*](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#renderAjax%28%29-detail) method to render your view when it is requested via ajax. I assume that you use `actionLocating` to render your view for page get request and for ajax. So before you call *render* in your controller, check if this is ajax request or not:

```
$renderMethod = Yii::$app->request->isAjax ? 'renderAjax' : 'render';

return $this->$renderMethod('locating', $viewParams);
```

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for answering. Please excuse my late response...I was travelling.

Comment: I tried renderAjax before, also tried your code...same result: dataProvider gets created correctly but still no render

Comment: maybee the error is here: `$dataProvider1 = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);` ...gonna check it out.

Comment: how your js code looks like ? you post it exactly as it is in to your question ?

Comment: yes, it's the same code, I also tried it with `$.ajax` but same result

Comment: If I do `document.write(data)` the map doesn't get rendered because of the problem with asynchronous loading: see [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async?hl=es) and [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003644/async-loading-javascript-with-document-write)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionLocating()
{
    $searchModel = new ViewMachinesSearch();
    $dataProvider1 = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProvider1->pagination = false;
    $model = new TrackingForm();

    if (Yii::$app->request->post()){
        $model->machine_select = Yii::$app->request->post('keylist');
        $machines = $model->machine_select;
    }else{
        $machines = $model->getMachines();
    }

    if(!in_array(Yii::$app->user->identity->company_id, Yii::$app->CompaniesByUser->getCompaniesByUser(21))){
        $query = New Query;
        $query  ->select(['licenceplate', 'identifier', 'timestamp', 'lat', 'lng'])
                ->from('gps_live')
                ->where(['machine_id' => $machines])
                ->orderBy(['timestamp' => SORT_DESC]);
    }else{
        $subquery = New Query;
        $subquery   ->select(['licenceplate', 'identifier', 'timestamp', 'lat', 'lng'])
                    ->from('btc_m1_v1_1')
                    ->join('INNER JOIN', 'machine', 'machine.id_machine = machine_id')
                    ->where(['machine_id' => $machines])
                    ->andWhere('lat <> 0')
                    ->andWhere('lng <> 0')
                    ->orderBy(['timestamp' => SORT_DESC]);
        $query = New Query;
        $query  ->from(['sub' => $subquery])
                ->groupBy(['sub.licenceplate'])
                ->all();
    }

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider(['query'=>$query, 'pagination'=>false]);
    return $this->render('locating', [
        'model' => $model,
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create some function on your base controller to make sure it was rendered as an ajax or not, the code seems like this.

```
protected function renderIsAjax($view, $params = [])
{
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        return $this->renderAjax($view, $params);
    } else {
        return $this->render($view, $params);
}
```

then in your controller just call that method

```
return $this->renderIsAjax('locating', [
    'model' => $model,
    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]);
```